# Select user according to time php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am providing 24 hours trial membership in my android application. I do not know more about PHP. I want check user registration time and want disable trial membership if 24 hours got passed. I have made little PHP file for that.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, email, registration_time FROM user WHERE trial = 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        $id = $row[0];
        $email = $row[1];
        $registrationTime = strtotime($row[2]);
        $currentTime = strtotime("-1 day");
        if($currentTime > $registrationTime) {
            $update = "UPDATE user SET trial = 0 WHERE email = '$email'";
            $conn->query($update);

            $update = "UPDATE number_list SET disable = 1 WHERE user_id = $id";
            $conn->query($update);
        }
    }
}
```

Its not providing any result even I have one user which time passed more than 48 hours.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What is your `strtotime($row[2])` printed value?

Comment: Consider storing [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) `+` [`86400`](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=seconds+in+a+day&oq=seconds+in+a+day&aqs=chrome..69i57j6j0l4.2771j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) instead of a date string. Then when you are checking, just do `if (time() >= $end_time_for_trial) {  }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this and check

```
$currentTime=date('m-d-Y',strtotime($registrationTime . "-1 days"))
```

Comment: Why would that work? Consider explaining your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a **prepared statement** to update the database for all the users with the same email (your first update query). Also see the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

If someone registers with an e-mail address like `test'; DROP ALL TABLES; --@gmail.com`<sup>1</sup>  this code will dutifully remove your database. Never put user data into code directly like that.

Now let's look at the example code;

```
$sql = "SELECT id, email, registration_time FROM user WHERE trial = 1"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
```

You're saying there is no result at all. I assume that you've tested the output with a debug statement. E.g. putting `echo 'users exist';` in between here. The first thing to do would be to check your `user` table if there are any rows. Does this SQL query produce results?

Assuming that it does, there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the SQL statement. Assuming you have a table called `user` with four columns `id`, `email`, `registration_time`, and `trial` it should produce results.

Next, what you want to do is read the [query function documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). As you can see there, when a query fails, for whatever reason, it returns FALSE. Try writing an 'else' code block and logging the error that occurs. You can fetch it using the error function `mysqli::error`. Try appending this code;

```
} else { 
    echo "MySQL Error: " . $conn->error;
}
```

Where you can replace the `echo` with your error handling of choice. 
It's probably a good idea to write a **wrapper** for mysqli if you're going to execute more than a few queries in your application. That way, you can write error handlers in your wrapper class for what your application should do if a query or database connection fails.

What could also be the case is that, while your initial query succeeds and fetches some rows, the time check fails. You may want to do some stricter date/time parsing than using `strtotime` and hoping for the best. Assuming you're using a TIMESTAMP column to store the data, you can use this:

```
function readDatabaseTimestampValue($value) {
    $dateTime = date_create_from_format("Y-m-d H:i:s", $value);
    $timestamp = $dateTime->getTimestamp();
    return $timestamp;
}
```

Check the exact time data returned from your database. Dates and times are complicated, and if things are reinterpreted, say the day number in SQL may become the year in the PHP app, which can cause strange bugs. E.g. you can do this by doing say:

```
echo "24 hours ago: " . strtotime("-1 day") . ", user data: " . $row[2];
```

Next, you probably have some bugs in the logic. '24 hours ago' is better done by doing this, as using '-1 day' will cause weird issues when people mess with the calendar:

```
$timestamp = time() - 86400;
```

There's 86,400 seconds in a day (well, excluding DST and leap seconds, but you want 24 hours of subscription time, not 23 hours around the 21<sup>st</sup> of March).

Finally, there's problems if the same E-mail address is present more than once in the table. You will set 'trial' to 0 for one user, but may set the 'disable' flag for another if two users register within the same 24-hour period with the same e-mail. If the latter is guaranteed to be unique then this is no issue. Otherwise, you may want to update by `id` in both tables.

Next, we can look at some optimization. Right now, you fetch everything from the database. But you can do much better/faster by having an **index** on registrationTime, and using the database's sorting features. E.g. let's say we know the exact date/time of 24 hours ago as `$yesterday` in PHP we can write a query like:

```
SELECT id, email, registration_time FROM user WHERE trial = 1 AND registration_time > ?
```

Bind the `$yesterday` variable to the parameter. Now you no longer need the `if()` statement; the database does it for you. Also, as your database grows, you're not checking the old records one-by-one every time the code runs.

<sup>1</sup>Note, that may not be a legal e-mail address, but there's probably ways to do evil things even with a legal mail address.